# How to create a template helper after a template has been rendered in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

```
Template.prices.rendered = function() {

  OrderFormContent = new Meteor.Collection(null);

  var orderSubmission = function() {
    //code that inserts stuff into the OrderFormContent collection
    //the key **sqft** is assigned the value of **4000**   };

  orderSubmission();

};

Template.prices.helpers({ 
  sqft: function() {
    return OrderFormContent.findOne().sqft;   
  } 
});
```

The code above doesn't load. Meteor tries to create the helper of {{sqft}} but can't because OrderFormContent does not get defined until after the page renders. It appears that Meteor tries to define the helper before the page is even rendered.

But I need to define this helper. And I need to have it defined only after the template is rendered (not created).

I cannot just nest `Template.prices.helpers` inside `Template.prices.rendered`.

**Clarification:**

If I comment out the `Template.prices.helpers` code the page will load. If I then run `OrderFormContent.findOne().sqft` manually in the console a value of 4000 is returned.

When I un-comment the `Template.prices.helpers` code the page fails to load and I get a `Exception from Deps recompute function: ReferenceError: OrderFormContent is not defined` error.

Comment: Why? From the code you've posted I cannot see any reason why you would want to define the helper later.

Comment: What do you mean? The `OrderFormContent` collection does not exist at the time the `{{sqft}}` helper is being defined. So Meteor throws an error saying that `OrderFormContent` is undefined and the page doesn't even load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Defining global variables inside a function is against good practices of Javascript, and is invalid in strict mode (and thus will be invalid in the future when strict mode becomes a standard).

2) You can easily achieve your goal without defining helper after rendering. In fact, the error is not thrown when the helper is **created,** but when it's **called.** To fix this problem it's enough to include a simple check.

```
var OrderFormContent = null;
var orderFormContentDep = new Deps.Dependency();

Template.prices.rendered = function() {
  OrderFormContent = new Meteor.Collection(null);
  ...
  orderFormContentDep.changed();
};

Template.prices.helpers({
  sqft: function() {
    orderFormContentDep.depend();
    if(!OrderFormContent) return null;
    var item = OrderFormContent.findOne();
    if(!item) return null;
    return item.sqft;
  });
});
```

Comment: `OrderFormContent` is undefined and the helper returns nothing when I use this code. The helper should be returning `4000`

Comment: To re-iterate, if I comment out `Template.prices.helpers`, the page loads and `OrderFormContent.findOne().sqft` works and returns `4000` when I call it from the console after the page has finished loading. But when I put this exact code into `Template.prices.helpers`, the page no longer loads and it says that the collection `OrderFormContent` is not defined.

Comment: Right, you need to add reactivity manually to the piece. I've added `orderFormContentDep` dependency to the example, it should now refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

When I got that error I moved the template helper to the client js and it went away. Only that didn't work for my purposes because it executed too often. So, I put it into an Iron Router route method to be rendered.